# Error message appearing on wrong Joomla page

Tags: joomla, alert, registration

On my registration page, if users make a mistake in their email address or create a password which is too short (I require a minimum of 7 characters including at least 1 number), then after clicking 'register' an error message alert should appear.

However, after clicking register, the page appears to refresh with no message to the user as to why their registration hasn't worked. Furthermore, if I navigate to another page on my website, the alerts will appear on that page instead!

I use Joomla 3.7.2

Can anyone advise me on what to do?

**Note:** To replicate the issue, try registering using two different email addresses **or** create a password with fewer than 7 characters. Here is the problem page: [www.radiologycafe.com/create-an-account](http://www.radiologycafe.com/create-an-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue for now.

It was a problem with the SiteGround Supercaching feature. I disabled this by going to the 'System - jSGCache' Joomla plugin on my Joomla website and changing the 'SG Cache Status' from 'enabled' to 'disabled'.

The alerts are now working correctly.